# Hypothetical - Optimal fixed income portfolio for Volcker period

Tags: united-states, bonds

[Paul Volcker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Volcker) raised the interest rate to over 20% in the early 80s. I was thinking to myself, if I had to manage my finances during such a time, how would I do.

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/why-interest-rates-have-inverse-relationship-bond-prices/), bonds have an inverse relationship to rate policy. So upon a rate hike, outstanding bonds would trade at a discount to compete with new issues. I have a cursory understanding of duration and convexity (rate of change of duration) but won't pretend to understand all the mechanics.

So if I was tasked to choose a point in time (presumably) shortly before the Volcker hike to position myself, I'm not sure I have the right blueprint. Nonetheless, I'll hazard a portfolio design for $100,000:

#### Hypothetical 1976 plan

- Teleport myself back in time to 1976 year before the big hike
- Put everything into 1yr t-bills
- Roll over every year until 1980
- Then lock in my 15% yielding 30yr (with the clairvoyance that there
  are no further hikes)
- Then in 2012 or so, I will have had a decent return

[image]

[image]

But I'm not that confident I played it right, feels like I'm missing something. Inflation-adjusted returns might be bad. Maybe TIPs would have been better?

### Question

With $100,000 to invest, and afforded the clairvoyance we have in 2022, what is the best maturity schedule we could design for a fixed-income only portfolio in 1976? (treasuries only, not looking at corporate credit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong - you'd essentially be buying bonds at their highest point yield-wise and would make a guaranteed 15% annually over 30 years (6,621% overall).

> Inflation-adjusted returns might be bad. Maybe TIPs would have been better?

TIPS give you a guaranteed *real* rate of return based on *expected* inflation. So they'd only be a better investment if inflation over the next 30 years ended up higher than was expected in 1980.